# Why $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}$?

Tags: analysis

Why $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}$( and hence equals to $1$)?

Any rigorous reason? (i.e. not just say by letting $t=x^2+y^2$.)

Comment: use polar coordinates...

Comment: @Eric In fact $t=x^2+y^2$ seems to me pretty rigorous, doesn't it?

Comment: Why the polar coordinates method is consistent with the original $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: @MiguelAtencia  So do you think $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^\sqrt{2}+\log y^4)}{x^\sqrt{2}+\log y^4}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$?

Comment: @Eric No, because $\log y^4$ is not defined at $y=0$. Well, ok, let us be rigourous: $t(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is continuous, so it swaps with the limit; and $t(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a point of view I like. The fact that $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$$ means precisely that the function $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $$\phi(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin t}t;&t\neq0,\\1;&t=0,\end{cases}$$ is continuous. Therefore, we have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\phi(x^2+y^2)=\phi(0)=1.$$ The first equality holds because the definition of limit doesn't involve the value of the function at $(0,0)$ and the second equality holds because $\phi(x^2+y^2)$ is continuous (since it is the composition of two continuous functions).

Comment: Thanks! I love your argument!! Can you also help me check why the *change to polar coordinates* method to compute the limits of some several variables functions that calculus textbooks often used also work?

Comment: Can't it just be thought as the compositions of some functions? Just like the example of this post. Let $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^+\times[0,2\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^2$  defined by $\Psi(r,\phi)=(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$, and regard $\lim f(x,y)$ as $f(r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$, but I can't figure out the left process..

Comment: (I have re-elaborated my comments in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991165/why-is-the-change-to-polar-coordinate-method-valid-in-computing-limits), so I have removed them here.)

Answer (score 0):

Using $x = t \cos \alpha $ and $y = t \sin \alpha$, then:

$$ \frac{ \sin (x^2 + y^2 ) }{x^2+y^2} =  \frac{ \sin (t^2(\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha)) }{t^2(\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha)} = \frac{ \sin (t^2) }{t^2}$$
.

Note as $x,y \to 0,0$, then $t \to 0 $.

Comment: Can you show rigorously that $x,y\to 0$ then $t\to 0$? Not just say by "intuition".

Comment: @Eric Just solve the first two equations for t and then take the limit seperately